# Does Diophantine equation $(5x-1)yz=(2088k+2010+x)(z-y)$ has solution for every $k\geq1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, problem-solving, congruences

I would like to show if the following equation is soluble for every positive integer $k$
$$
(5x-1)yz=(2088k+2010+x)(z-y),
$$
where $x,y,z$ are positive integers and $z>y$.
I am trying to divide $k$ to some congruence classes modulo some number and continue this to cover all cases, but this method takes long time.

My question is first if this equation is soluble for every $k>0$. second if there is a shorter way than investigating residue classes modulo some number?

Thanks.

Comment: I’ve produced a few solutions to this fascinating equation and found results for all $k$ up to $444$. I’ve also noticed many solutions that fit within patterns that can be used to produce parametric solutions. Some of these give very useful results, such as solutions for all $k=0mod19$. However, the vast majority are of questionable value, such as a general solution for $k=47mod49$. May I ask if I’m just duplicating your work, or would you like me to post a partial answer?

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1$ the solutions are

$(x=2\land y=82\land z=100)\lor (x=2\land y=400\land z=3280)\lor (x=2\land
   y=410\land z=4100)\lor (x=2\land y=450\land z=36900)\lor (x=2\land y=451\land
   z=45100)\lor (x=2\land y=455\land z=373100)\lor (x=6\land y=108\land
   z=456)\lor (x=7\land y=120\land z=19704)\lor (x=25\land y=21\land z=57)\lor
   (x=25\land y=33\land z=4389)\lor (x=39\land y=21\land z=1379)\lor (x=87\land
   y=9\land z=135)\lor (x=273\land y=3\land z=47)\lor (x=1017\land y=1\land
   z=165)$

Now we know that $y z \geq z-y$ when $z>y>0$, So the above equation could make sense to look for solution when $2088k+2010+x \geq 5x-1$, solving for $x$ we get that $x\leq \frac{1}{4} (2088 k+2011)$, which imply that **For any fixed $k$ there are only finitely many solutions**.

The rest is to check them by computer search.